# Convergent sequences of points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_{n)n \in N}$ and $(b_{n)n \in N}$ be two convergent sequences of points in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Prove if $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$, then $||a_n - b_n|| \rightarrow ||a-b||$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I know that if they $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n  \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ for only sufficiently large values of n using the squeeze theorem. Would the same apply here or is there something else to be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$, it is clear that $a_n - b_n \to a-b$. To see this, consider the inequality
$$\|a_n - b_n - a+b\| \le \|a_n - a\| + \|b_n - b\|$$
for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Hence, your question boils down to showing that if $c_n \to c$, then $\|c_n\| \to \|c\|$. The triangle inequality comes to our rescue once again. We have
$$\|c_n\| \le \|c_n - c\| + \|c\| \tag{1}$$
and
$$\|c\| \le \|c_n - c\| + \|c_n\| \tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$|\|c_n\| - \|c\|| \le \|c_n - c\|$$
so that when $\|c_n - c\| \to 0$, we also have $\|c_n\| \to \|c\|$. Apply this result to $c_n = a_n - b_n$ to get the desired conclusion.

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you so much!